# Proper use of for-each-group in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml sample:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <item_id>1</item_id>
        <item_name>item 1</item_name>
        <group_id>1</group_id>
        <group_name>group 1</group_name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>2</item_id>
        <item_name>item 2</item_name>
        <group_id>1</group_id>
        <group_name>group 1</group_name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>3</item_id>
        <item_name>item 3</item_name>
        <group_id>2</group_id>
        <group_name>group 2</group_name>
    </item>
</items>
```

which I need transformed into the following csv format:

```
1,item 1
2,item 2
3,item 3
1,group 1
2,group 2
```

In the xml, item_id will always be followed by item_name. The item name will not always be concat('item_',#). It could be an description such as 'toothpaste'. Items will never be repeated in the file but occasionally the group_id->group_name pairing will not always be 1-1. In this case, it is preferred to take the first pairing.

I am accomplishing this using a 'for-each-group' statement but it seems a bit hacky. Are there any downsides to this approach? What are some better ways to accomplish this?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="list_format">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'item'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="list_format">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'group'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="list_format">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>

    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list_id" select="concat($list,'_id')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list_name" select="concat($list,'_name')"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="/items/item" group-by="*[name()=$list_id]">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$list_id]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$list_id]"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$list_name]"/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `<item_id>1</item_id>` will always be followed by: `<item_name>item 1</item_name>` (or, generally, by `item_name` element with the same value)? If this is guaranteed, then you must tell us what are the additional rules for choosing with of the many possible `item_name` value to display together with a given `item_id` element balue.

Comment: In this file, item_id will always be followed by item_name. The item name will not always be concat('item_',#). It could be an description such as 'toothpaste'. Items will never be repeated in the file but occasionally the group_id->group_name pairing will not always be 1-1. In this case, it is preferred to take the first pairing.

Comment: user1193339: You have to edit the question and provide this information there -- otherwise it is ambiguous and people would not prefer to solve it by guessing.

Comment: Also, your data isn't too representable -- the `item` elements don't have repeating ids and values, so why use grouping at all?

Comment: I guess the main issue I have is how to handle multiple group_id->group_name pairs and only pull the first occurrence each group_id and the name associated with that id. I don't specifically need the grouping functionality it just seems to give me the functionality I want although I think there is a more correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a simple and short XSLT 2.0 (as requested) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/group_id" group-by=".">
    <xsl:value-of separator="," select="../*[starts-with(name(), 'group_')]"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
     <xsl:value-of separator="," select="*[starts-with(name(), 'item_')]"/>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <item_id>1</item_id>
        <item_name>item 1</item_name>
        <group_id>1</group_id>
        <group_name>group 1</group_name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>2</item_id>
        <item_name>item 2</item_name>
        <group_id>1</group_id>
        <group_name>group 1</group_name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>3</item_id>
        <item_name>item 3</item_name>
        <group_id>2</group_id>
        <group_name>group 2</group_name>
    </item>
</items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1,item 1
2,item 2
3,item 3
1,group 1
2,group 2
```

Answer (score 1):

hmmm .. not really a downside but it doesn't work in XSLT 1.0 as it doesn't support `for-each-group` :-/

I don't think you would need XSLT 1.0 solution .. but still am posting my work :) Check this out!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:call-template name="items_grouping">
      <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'item'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="items_grouping">
      <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'group'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="items_grouping">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list_id" select="concat($list,'_id')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list_name" select="concat($list,'_name')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[name()=$list_id and not(.= ../preceding-sibling::item/*[name()=$list_id]/.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,',')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../*[name()=$list_name]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Used same methodology of yours .. only change is `'preceding-sibling'`

 and also for this code, **order of child-nodes of `<item>` doesn't matter**